# Is a 48 V DC circuit breaker OK to use on a 48 V LiFePO4 battery powered circuit?

Tags: batteries, dc, circuit-protection

I have a 48 V LiFePO4 battery pack sitting at around 53.6 V at full charge and around 56 - 56.8 V while charging. Is it OK to use a DC 48 V, 100 A circuit breaker/switch/button etc. or do I need to make sure the ratings are above the actual maximum voltage?

If I need to make sure they are larger than the actual voltage, is there any penalty to choosing one rated way higher, like, say, a DC 500 V, 100 A circuit breaker? Because finding ones that are closer but above is proving difficult.

Comment: The 500 V one should be fine, though I'd question where you found one with those ratings at DC!

Comment: https://www.tro.com.au/Noark-Moulded-Case-Circuit-Breaker-2-Pole-500V-DC-100A

Comment: @Hearth high voltage DC circuit breakers are required to disconnect solar panels so they're getting easier to find, although at "solar" prices usually!